# compare array numbers in pseudocode

Tags: arrays, numbers, compare, pseudocode

got array A and B as input with the (same) length of n. it doesnt matter at which place the numbers are or unique.

A = [1,2,3,2] and B=[2,1,3,2] should give true.
after comparison the output is true if if not it is false

so far I dont have much experience with if loops and this is how little I got

```
A: array_of_numbers;
B: array_of_numbers;
n := |A|;
m := |B|;
for i = 1..n do
```

and at that point I dont know how to proceed as I get only gibberish. I thought the first number to be checked with the first number of B, if they match proceed to i+1. if not i and j+1. I guess the loop goes untill i and last number of B dont match. the other loop from last A to last B. and if that fails I get false. but I dont know how to put it

Comment: Is there any limitations? Can you use extra space? What about running time?

Comment: the space is not limited. the running time is supposed to be as efficient as possible. I would be happy with something that runs and I can wrap my head around, I dont understand it yet.

Comment: Any limitation. About input? Like highest possible value in array?

Comment: dont thinks so(or n?). A and B are arrays of length "n" from numbers {1...n}. every number can be more than once in it and not all numbers have to be there

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are in size n and the values are bounded between 1..m you can use backet sort (which cost o(m) size) which sort the array in o(n). Both arrays then will be sorted in o(n). Then run on the arrays with two indices to make sure that each value appear in both arrays.. Which is also o(n). Total cost: running time o(n), memory o(m).
Good luck!